# Google Map not displaying in browser

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

Hi i am following this tutorial in youtube on how to implement google map. When i run the code, the google map show's nothing at all. I still new to ionic :)

Link to tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jD5yYX1KWXA&t=14s

home.html

[image]

home.ts

[image]
[image]

Result at browser:
[image]

Browser html source code for map
[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's not being rendered in the browser? What does the markup look like (of the map div) after the page has loaded? Do you need a width or a fixed height, rather than 100%?

Comment: hi i have updated my post. I don't think it's the width or height being 100%. But i guess something i am missing which i don't know

Comment: If on chrome, right click and select "inspect element". Then find your map html, copy it and paste it here.

Comment: You are required to post your markup and code, not a picture of the code which cannot be searched or copied.

Comment: The html source code look fine to me

Comment: Why would you post pictures of code?  They are worthless if you want help debugging.  You should post a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using native based Google Maps SDK, its not supposed to run on browser.

The Native SDKs require `Cordova`, so will only run when installed on devices/ emulator, not through the browser.

If you want to run it on browser, use web based `Javascript SDK`.

Answer (score 0):

you must add api in googlemap go to developers tools and give. new api

Comment: i generated the key and have the run the following command ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY_IS_HERE" and also added the script tag for google map in index.html  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[key]&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>